# Plugging content into a tikzpicture environment through a `tl` variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

Automating the tikzpicture environment: 
the idea is to define (a) `[options]` or `[styles]` and (b) `content` in a `tikzpicture` environment not manually by plugging literal strings into the environment, but by plugging in `tl` variables, the value of which can be generated in macros designated for that task. Using @egreg 's answer to @Tobi' s `question asked Feb 5 '16 at 19:12`
solves the problem for `options/styles`, but I am still having to come to terms with how to supply `content`. P.S. If it's again in the `x`s, `n`s or `V`s, I will have to be shown a fifth time.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. Friday 1 December 2017
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_start_tikzpicture:n {\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__rn_start_tikzpicture:n { V }
\tl_new:N \l_rn_Aux_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl

\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl
\cs_new:Npn \rn_generateTikzStyle_FR:n #1
%  PARAMETERS: #1 dummy variable 
%  RETURNS: \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl to be plugged into tikzpicture environment
  {
\group_begin:
    % number of levels determines the values for level distance, sibling   distance, 
    % and node style. Computing and setting the variable adds no difficulties
    % to setting it in the following way: 
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl {level~distance=10mm,
  every~node/.style={circle,draw,inner~sep=1pt},
  level~1/.style={sibling~distance=30mm}}  
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_generateTikzStyle_FR:n

\tl_new:N \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl
\cs_new:Npn \rn_generateTikzContent_FR:n #1
%  PARAMETERS: #1 dummy parameter specifys the key values for the nodes of the tree.
%  RETURNS: \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl to be plugged into tikzpicture environment
  {
\group_begin:
    %  \tl_gset:Nn \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {\node{10}child{node{5}}child{node{15}};} 
    % ... setting the return variable in above fashion works, but does not address the 
    % problem as in actual practice the content string is computed as follows: from the
    % list of keys presented in parameter #1 a \_seq variable is computed as a 
    % representation of the tree, which then serves as the basis for computing the 
    % content for the tabular and the tikzpicture environments. Tabular is bedded dow
    % and works, tikzpicture content is computed by a post-order traversal of the nodes
    % of the tree, resulting in following steps in building the content string: 
    \tl_gclear:N \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl
    % visiting node key = 5:    
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_Aux_tl {5}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {child{node{\l_rn_Aux_tl}}}
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {\l_rn_auxOne_tl}
    % visiting node key = 15:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_Aux_tl {15}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {child{node{\l_rn_Aux_tl}}}
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {\l_rn_auxOne_tl}
    % visiting root of subtree, key = 10:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_Aux_tl {10}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {\node{\l_rn_Aux_tl}}
    \tl_gput_left:Nn \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {\l_rn_auxOne_tl}
%    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl {;}
\group_end:
  }  %  \rn_generateTikzContent_FR:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myShowTree{O{10,5,15}}
%  NOTE: Parameter `#1` lists the key values for which a binary search tree is 
% to be built. In this MWE `#1` is merely a dummy parameter and is as such passed
% to the macros that compute `content` and `style`. 
  {
    \rn_generateTikzStyle_FR:n {#1}
    \rn_generateTikzContent_FR:n {#1}
    \__rn_start_tikzpicture:V \g_rn_tikzStyle_FR_tl
      % my string is ineffective, but at least it does not flag compile ERROR 
      \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl ;  
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }  %  \myShowTree
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\section{Native tikzpicture}
The subject of the following discussion:

\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=10mm,
every node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm}]
\node{10}child{node{5}}child{node{15}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Style and Content both supplied as parameters}
\myShowTree[10,5,15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is in the `x`s.

Comment: I think that you should also show the general syntax you’d like for a binary tree

Comment: @egreg ... shall do, but I will have to keep it general and it will have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: I would suggest looking at `forest`.

Comment: @egreg `forest` looks useful, as does`prooftrees` which builds on it. My purpose in writing a set of macros for trees (and matrix manipulation) is to demonstrate, primarily to myself at this stage, the power of `expl3`. Using existing packages I found myself time and again shovelling large quantities of tokens like `&`, `node`, `child` etc.  into `tabular` and `tikzpicture` environments. I wanted to escape from that and now have a set of macros based on `expl3` that support that aim. They work, but are quite large and still extremely messy/ugly, hence unpublishable as `MWEs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, again, in the expansion.

The first bit works because in the end you expand everything with an `x`. But in the next two versions you are not expanding (and if you change, you might come to an error with `\node`). Here I try to explain, and tell you what you should do in my opinion.

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_Aux_tl { 5 }
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl { child{node{\l_rn_Aux_tl}} }
\tl_gput_right:Nx \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl { \l_rn_auxOne_tl }
```

with the first line you save `5` inside the aux token list; with the second line you save `child{node{\l_rn_aux_tl}}` inside the auxone tokenlist; with the third line you expand everything resulting in `child{node{5}}` and you add that to tikzcontent_fr token list. You are not doing the correct thing step by step, but in the end you end up with the correct thing.

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_Aux_tl { 15 }
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl { child{node{\l_rn_Aux_tl}} }
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl { \l_rn_auxOne_tl }
```

but here you forgot the `x`, so... with the first line you save `15` inside the aux token list; with the second line you save `child{node{\l_rn_aux_tl}}` inside the auxone tokenlist; with the third line you *do not* expand anything resulting in `\l_rn_auxone_tl` and you add that to tikzcontent_fr token list. Now, that token list looks like `child{node{5}}\l_rn_auxone_tl`.

In the third step you end up with `\l_rn_auxone_tl child{node{5}}\l_rn_auxone_tl`. That will expand in the end to something, but that's not what you want. You wanted it to be `\node{10}child{node{5}}child{node{15}}`.

---

What you should do is do each step right, and that way it will work.

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_Aux_tl { 5 }
```

That's okey, you store `5` in the token list. Then in the next step you want to expand the current value of `\l_rn_aux_tl` to `5`, not leave the `\l_rn_aux_tl` there, so you use `x`:

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl { child{node{\l_rn_Aux_tl}} }
```

So you get `child{node{5}}` saved in that token list; then you want *that* value added to the global token list, you don't want to expand with an `x` here, you just want the value (basically, expand once to get the contents, nothing more).

```
\tl_gput_right:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxOne_tl
```

Doing that, for each step, leaves you with correct results (i.e., `:Nn`, `:Nx`, and then `:NV`).

In your last step you are adding `\node` into the token list, it is not protected so gives an error. You can correct that by using `\exp_not:N` to stop expansion.

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_Aux_tl { 10 }
\tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl { \exp_not:N \node {\l_rn_Aux_tl} }
\tl_gput_left:NV \g_rn_tikzContent_FR_tl \l_rn_auxOne_tl
```

Comment: I followed your explanations and repaired my code accordingly, and never have I seen a more beautful 3-node tree! I learnt a lot this morning!